# do tags into clickable tags filters for jquery table - yadcf

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, yadcf

I see this filtering yadcf demo for Datatables: [Live Demo](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_select2.html)
You can filter table by tags but you can't click on `Tag1` or `Tag2` for use them like filtering table results and return only rows that have `Tag1` or `Tag2`.
is possible use tag inside table like a cliccable tags filters mode?
Which code must edit/add in [jquery.datatables.yadcf.js](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js)?

In the demo above this is part of code. How implement my feature request in `column_number: 4` or tag column?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';

    //----------------------------------------------
    // this is the code for column tag
    //----------------------------------------------

    oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bStateSave": true
    }).yadcf([{

     ......
     ......

       {
        column_number: 4,
        select_type: 'select2',
        select_type_options: {
            width: '150px'
            placeholder: 'Select tag',
            allowClear: true  // show 'x' (remove) next to selection inside the select itself
        },
        column_data_type: "html",
        html_data_type: "text",
        filter_reset_button_text: false // hide yadcf reset button
    }]);

    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
```

Which of these parameters must be edited?

```
column_number
filter_type
custom_func
data
column_data_type
text_data_delimiter
html_data_type
filter_container_id
filter_default_label
filter_reset_button_text
enable_auto_complete
sort_as
sort_order
date_format
ignore_char
filter_match_mode
select_type
select_type_options
case_insensitive
filter_delay
```

Comment: you mean that you wish to be able to click on the Tag that is inside the table row itself and not on the drop down in the header?

Comment: yes, just so, inside table row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved in the following ways

1) call this code upon page ready (note that your selector probably will be different)

```
$('#example').on('click',".label.lightblue", function () {
  yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[4, $(this).text()]]);
});
```

2) attach onclick event to your "tags" , something like this `onclick="yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[4, 'Tag1']]);"`

Comment: I try to integrate but something is wrong. Can you check my code, please? http://pastebin.com/PzdC0vBf if my code integration is wrong can you repaste correctly on pastebin or JSFiddle, please?

Comment: @user3520363 , you need to place the `$(".label.lightblue" ).on( "click", function() {....` code right after the `$('#example').dataTable().yadcf([...` code (inside the `$(document).ready(function(){...` code block

Comment: thank you Daniel. I very like tag filter because it can be very useful if you want to `explore` and do not typing values each time among many musical genres, actors name, films etc. You should add this feature in the future for yadcf.